# VpnClientRootCertificateDataInvalid : Point-to-site

Tags: azure, azure-vpn

We have a Point-to-site configuration set up in the Azure Virtual network gateway and there are uploaded Root certificates. Two certificates expired. I would like to remove them from the portal and replace them with new ones. It is not possible. Although I can remove them, the save option isn´t available. Also it isn´t possible to save a new certificate.

I tried to remove expired certificates through a powershell command:

```
az network vnet-gateway root-cert delete --resource-group MyGroup --name **MyCert1** --gateway-
name MyGateway
```

There was an error message:

> (VpnClientRootCertificateDataInvalid) Data for certificate
> /subscriptions/XYZ/resourceGroups/MyGroup/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworkGateway
> s/MyGateway/vpnClientRootCertificates/**MyCert2** is invalid.

There was another error message that the second expired certificate is wrong.

Could you help me with this problem?
Thanks

Comment: When you said," the save option isn´t available." refresh your web browser? access the portal in private mode? Is that helpful?

Comment: No. I tried it. it didn't help